# Добавить перенос строки к каждоый строчке

Tags: python, строки

Всем прривет, я туплю и не могу добавить перенос строки к каждой строчке, чтобы у меня на выходе не получалась одна длиннющая строка.

```
with open('purchase_log.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    with open('visit_log.csv', 'r') as f2:
        with open('funnel.csv.csv', 'w') as f3:
            for line in f2:
                new_line = line.strip().split(' ')
                if purchases.get(new_line[0]):
                    new_line.append(purchases.get(new_line[0]))
                    f3.write(json.dumps(new_line, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Comment: `f3.write(json.dumps(new_line, ensure_ascii=False) + '\n')`?

Answer (score 0):

За перенос на другую строку отвечает '\n'.

```
print('Первая строка\nВторая строка)
```

Comment: Это я знаю, я не понимаю, куда мне поставить /n.  Я так понимаю, в последнюю строку, где я записываю результаты в файл. Но в каком месте, мне все время выдает ошибки.

Comment: Прошу прощения, '\n' отвечает за перенос!(в ответе я отредактировал) Ставьте его перед тем символом, который вам нужно перенести.

Comment: f3.write(json.dumps(new_line + '\n', ensure_ascii=False) 
?

Comment: Нет, попробуйте после new_line добавить '\n'.

Comment: Тогда я получаю 
File "<ipython-input-125-c35bf98bb459>", line 14
f3.write(json.dumps(new_line'\n'))
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Какой вывод после new_line? Пока не используйте '\n'.

Comment: Попробуйте так: new_line.append(purchases.get(new_line[0] + '\n' )), то есть измените 7-ую строчку на эту.

Comment: Попробовала, и что-то у меня ничего не работает. То есть ошибку не выдает, но и результат тоже. Не получается в этом варианте так, что значение ищется по ключу (new_line + '\n' )? И ведь тогда же не найдет...

Comment: Так, а такой вариант вы пробовали? f3.write(json.dumps(new_line, ensure_ascii=False) + '\n')

Comment: Спасибо. буду пробовать.

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо!

Comment: Не могли бы вы оценить моё решение?)

Answer (score 0):

```
new_line.append(purchases.get(new_line[0])+'\n')
```